# Django Sentry Giving an Error in Development Environment

Tags: django, sentry

I'm running django-sentry successfully in our staging and production environments, but on my development instance sentry doesn't appear to be logging.

I'm using manage runserver, and when a 500 error occurs I'm getting this in the console:

```
Development server is running at http://192.168.56.100:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
No handlers could be found for logger "sentry.errors"
[20/Apr/2011 17:26:56] "POST .... HTTP/1.1" 500 126470
```

I've set the following in local_settings:

```
DEBUG = True
SENTRY_TESTING = True
```

Google searches have turned up nothing for the "No handlers..." error message - any ideas?

Comment: Which Django version are you using in production and your dev?

Comment: 1.2.3 in production and 1.2.5 in dev

Comment: Are you using Django >= 1.3? They changed the Error 500 handling. Look here: [Logging in 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.3/#logging) I am having the same problem. Have you fund a way to get it working yet?

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py on your dev box that isn't logging, add something like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("sentry.errors")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

So assuming you're using the standard manage.py runserver on your development desktop, that will open a StreamHandler() which writes to standard error and you should see on your console.

You could also change StreamHandler() ---> FileHandler("/tmp/debug.log", "w")

The fact that it is logging to the sentry.errors handler says that there is a misconfiguration with your dev sentry configuration / settings.